# Out Of Memory Android Error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

Here is the basic function of my Fragment: 1. Retrieves Data from a backend service called Backendless.com (a name and a phone number) in its onCreate method. 2. Stores the data in a local SQlite database, which is then used to populate a ListView. The user does what they wants while in the fragment(Adds new contacts, deletes old ones and so on) 3. Saves the manipulated data from the SQlite database back to the backend service as soon as the user exits the Fragment. This happens within the onPause method. Everything works fine until the onPause() method is reached and then I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemory` Error

Here is my SQlite data manger class, which stores a name and phone number locally.

```
public class DBAdapter {
private final static String TAG = "DBAdapter";

//Field Names
public final static String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public final static String KEY_NAME = "name";
public final static String KEY_NUMBER = "number";

public final static String[] ALL_KEYS = {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_NUMBER};


//Database Info
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ContactsDatabase";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Contacts";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//SQL to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT"
                +");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context c){
    this.context = c;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public DBAdapter open(){
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    db.close();
}

public long insertRow(String name,String number){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,values);
}

public boolean deleteRow(long rowID){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,where,null) !=0;
}

public void deleteAll(){
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowID = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int)rowID));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
}

public Cursor getAllRows(){
    String where = null;
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a Specific row by rowID
public Cursor getRow(long rowID){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID;
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null,null);
    if (c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

//Change an existing row with new Data
public boolean updateRow(long rowID, String name, String num){
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" +rowID;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME,name);
    values.put(KEY_NUMBER,num);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,values,where,null)!=0;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        Log.v("Adapter", "UPDATED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        Log.v("Adapter", "DOWNGRADED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}}
```

AND HERE IS MY FRAGMENT CODE. The app keeps crashing when I'm trying to retrieve the data from my local Database on the onPause() method:

```
public class ContactsFragments extends Fragment {
public DBAdapter myDB;
EditText inputName,inputNumber;
private View view;
private Button saveButton, deleteAllButton;
public ListView myList;
public long rowClickedForEdit = -1;
public boolean shouldWeEdit = false;
private ArrayList<String> numbersForWeb = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> namesForWeb = new ArrayList<>();

public ContactsFragments() {setRetainInstance(true);}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String userEmail = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getEmail();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UE: " + userEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    retrieveDataFromCloud(userEmail);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_fragments, container, false);

    inputName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputNumber);
    saveButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    deleteAllButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.deleteAllButton);
    openDB();
    populateListView();
    listViewItemCancel();

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (shouldWeEdit) {
                myDB.updateRow(rowClickedForEdit,
                        inputName.getText().toString(),
                        inputNumber.getText().toString()
                );
                populateListView();
            } else {
                onClick_Add(v);
            }

            shouldWeEdit = false;
            inputName.setText("");
            inputNumber.setText("");
            inputName.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NAME");
            inputNumber.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NUMBER");
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    deleteAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClickDeleteAll(v);
            shouldWeEdit = false;
            inputName.setText("");
            inputNumber.setText("");
            inputName.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NAME");
            inputNumber.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NUMBER");
        }
    });

    myList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);

    return view;
}

private void openDB(){
    myDB = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    myDB.open();
}

public void onClick_Add(View v){
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputName.getText().toString())){
        myDB.insertRow(inputName.getText().toString(), inputNumber.getText().toString());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter A Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    populateListView();
}

public void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();


    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.KEY_NUMBER};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.customRowContactName,R.id.customRowContactNumber};

    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.contacts_custom_row,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs);

    myList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    myList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}

public void onClickDeleteAll(View v){
    myDB.deleteAll();
    populateListView();
}


private void listViewItemCancel(){
    myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            inputName.setText("");
            inputNumber.setText("");
            inputName.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NAME");
            inputNumber.setHint("ENTER CONTACT NUMBER");
            shouldWeEdit = false;
            populateListView();
        }
    });
}

class CursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;

    public CursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vix = inView;

        if (vix == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vix = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_custom_row, null);
        }
        this.c.moveToPosition(pos);

        String name = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
        String num = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NUMBER));
        final String id = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));

        TextView textName = (TextView) vix.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactName);
        textName.setText(name);
        final TextView textNum = (TextView) vix.findViewById(R.id.customRowContactNumber);
        textNum.setText(num);
        final TextView textCancel = (TextView)vix.findViewById(R.id.customRowCancelText);
        textCancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        final TextView deleteText = (TextView)vix.findViewById(R.id.customRowDeleteText);
        final TextView editInfo = (TextView)vix.findViewById(R.id.customRowEditText);

        deleteText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDB.deleteRow(Integer.valueOf(id));
                populateListView();
            }
        });

        editInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                inputName.setText("");
                inputNumber.setText("");
                inputName.setHint("ENTER NEW NAME");
                inputNumber.setHint("ENTER NEW NUMBER");
                rowClickedForEdit = Long.valueOf(id);
                shouldWeEdit = true;
            }
        });

        textNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                URI uri;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + textNum.getText().toString()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return vix;
    }
}

public void retrieveDataFromCloud(String userEmail){

    String whereClause = "userEmailID = '"+ userEmail +"'";
    BackendlessDataQuery dataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    dataQuery.setWhereClause( whereClause );

    Backendless.Persistence.of(LocalPhoneNum.class).find(dataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<LocalPhoneNum>>(){
        @Override
        public void handleResponse( BackendlessCollection<LocalPhoneNum> foundContacts )
        {
            List<String> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (LocalPhoneNum temp : foundContacts.getData()){
               dataArrayList.add(temp.getPhoneNum());
            }
            if (dataArrayList.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataArrayList.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void handleFault( BackendlessFault fault )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    ** ERROR OCCURS HERE
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        namesForWeb.add(data);
    }



    String userEmail = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getEmail();
    LocalPhoneNum localPhoneNum = new LocalPhoneNum(userEmail, "617 8", "mark");

    super.onPause();
    Backendless.Persistence.save(localPhoneNum, new AsyncCallback<LocalPhoneNum>() {

        @Override
        public void handleResponse(LocalPhoneNum localPhoneNum) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Saved To Cloud", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Not Saved To Cloud " + backendlessFault, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Is the app simply doing too much? Thank you!

Comment: Can you try reading data on a separate thread?

Comment: Can we show the stacktrace ?

Comment: @eenvincible Like an AsyncTask() that handles all the data saving in the onPause method?

Comment: It could be saving or reading data; you always ant to avoid clogging the UI thread